# Capybara: Unable to find css again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rspec, capybara

**page source (from save_and_open_page):**

```
<a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/slides/1" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
```

**spec/features/slides_spec.rb:**

```
scenario "Delete slide" do
    visit album_slides_url slide.album
    # save_and_open_page
    expect{page.find('btn btn-mini btn-danger').click}.to change(Slide, :count).by(-1)
  end
```

**error:**

```
Unable to find css "btn btn-mini btn-danger"
```

There are a few Q&A for similar issue but I didn't find any solution there. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS selectors classes are identified by starting with dots, easy to forget. Also, if you want to find an element which has all of the classes specified you can't have any whitespace in between them; otherwise it is looking for children.

```
page.find('.btn.btn-mini.btn-danger')
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also use

```
expect{click_link('Delete')}.to change(Slide, :count).by(-1)
```

Its much simpler to find the `text` i.e., `Delete` in this case of an `anchor` element (..) and fire `click_link` event on it.

Comment: I can't use it as I have more `Delete` buttons there. The one I need to click is different by 'btn-mini' CSS class. This is why I try to select it by CSS.

Comment: Thats fine. In that case Jacob's solution is perfect. BUT remember in that case also `.btn.btn-mini.btn-danger` should be unique for a single Delete link otherwise it will just find the first `Delete` link with the given classes and click on it.